# Replace String in a Binary Clipboard Dump from OneNote

Tags: powershell, autohotkey, onenote

I'm using an AHK script to dump the current clipboard contents to a file (which contains a copy of a part of Microsoft OneNote page to a file).

I would like to modify this binary file to search for a specific string and be able to import it back into AHK.

I tried the following but it looks like powershell is doing something additional to the file (like changing the encoding) and the import of the file into the clipboard is failing.

```
$ThisFile = 'B:\Users\Desktop\onenote-new-entry.txt'
$data = Get-Content $ThisFile
$data = $data.Replace('asdf','TESTREPLACE!')
$data | Out-File -encoding utf8 $ThisFile
```

Any suggestions on doing a string replace to the file without changing existing encoding?

I tried manually modifying in a text editor and it works fine. Obviously though I would like to have the modifications be done in mass and automatically which is why I need a script.

The text copied from OneNote and then dumped to file via AHK looks like this:
[image]

However, note the clipboard dump file has a lot of other meta-data as shown below when opened in an editor. To download for testing with PS, [click here](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AhD4wIhahXFSo-VNHCBmt45zGNiG_g?e=UfxKve):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Since your file is a *mix* of binary data and UTF-8 text, you cannot use *text* processing** (as you tried with `Out-File -Encoding utf8`), because the binary data would invariably be interpreted as text too, resulting in its corruption.

PowerShell offers no simple method for editing binary files, but **you can solve your problem via an auxiliary "hex string" representation of the file's bytes**:

```bash
# To compensate for a difference between Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) 7+
# with respect to how byte processing is requested: -Encoding Byte vs. -AsByteStream
$byteEncParam = 
  if ($IsCoreCLR) { @{ AsByteStream = $true } } 
  else            { @{ Encoding = 'Byte' } }

# Read the file *as a byte array*.
$ThisFile = 'B:\Users\Desktop\onenote-new-entry.txt'
$data = Get-Content @byteEncParam -ReadCount 0  $ThisFile

# Convert the array to a "hex string" in the form "nn-nn-nn-...",
# where nn represents a two-digit hex representation of each byte,
# e.g. '41-42' for 0x41, 0x42, which, if interpreted as a
# single-byte encoding (ASCII), is 'AB'.
$dataAsHexString = [BitConverter]::ToString($data)

# Define the search and replace strings, and convert them into
# "hex strings" too, using their UTF-8 byte representation.
$search = 'asdf'
$replacement = 'TESTREPLACE!'
$searchAsHexString = [BitConverter]::ToString([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($search))
$replaceAsHexString = [BitConverter]::ToString([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($replacement))

# Perform the replacement.
$dataAsHexString = $dataAsHexString.Replace($searchAsHexString, $replaceAsHexString)

# Convert he modified "hex string" back to a byte[] array.
$modifiedData = [byte[]] ($dataAsHexString -split '-' -replace '^', '0x')

# Save the byte array back to the file.
Set-Content @byteEncParam $ThisFile -Value $modifiedData
```

Note:

- As discussed in the comments, **in the case at hand this can only be expected to work if the search and the replacements strings are of the *same length***, because the file also contains *metadata* denoting the position and length of the embedded text parts. A replacement string of different length would require adjusting that metadata accordingly.
- The string replacement performed is (a) literal, and (b) case-*sensitive*, and (c) - for *accented* characters such as `é` - only works the if the input - like string literals in .NET - uses the *composed* [Unicode normalization form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) , where `é` is a *single* code point and encoded as such (resulting in a multi-byte UTF-8 escape sequence).
- More sophisticated replacements, such as [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based ones, would only be possible if you knew how to split the file data into binary and textual parts, allowing you to operate on the textual parts directly.

---

##### Optional reading: Modifying a UTF-8 file without incidental alterations:

Note:

- The following applies to text-only files that are UTF-8-encoded.
- Unless extra steps are taken, reading and re-saving such files in PowerShell can result in unwanted incidental changes to the file. Avoiding them is discussed below.

PowerShell never preserves information about the character encoding of an input file, such as one read with [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content). Also, unless you use `-Raw`, information about the specific *newline format* is lost, as well as whether the file had a *trailing* newline or not.

Assuming that you *know* the encoding:

- Read the file with `Get-Content -Raw` and specify the encoding with `-Encoding` (if necessary). You'll receive the file's content as a single, multi-line .NET string.
- Use [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) `-NoNewLine` to save the modified string back to the file, using `-Encoding` with the original encoding.

  - Caveat: In *Windows PowerShell*, `-Encoding utf8` invariably creates a UTF-8 file *with BOM*, unlike in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, which *defaults* to BOM-less UTF-8 and requires you to use `-Encoding utf8BOM` if you *want* a BOM.
  - If you're using Windows PowerShell and do *not* want a UTF-8 BOM, use 
    `$null =`[`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) `-Force ...` as a workaround, and pass the modified string to the `-Value` parameter.

Therefore:

```bash
$ThisFile = 'B:\Users\Desktop\onenote-new-entry.txt'
$data = Get-Content -Raw -Encoding utf8 $ThisFile
$data = $data.Replace('asdf','TESTREPLACE!')
# !! Note the caveat re BOM mentioned above.
$data | Set-Content -NoNewLine -Encoding utf8 $ThisFile
```

Streamlined reformulation, in a single pipeline:

```bash
(Get-Content -Raw -Encoding utf8 $ThisFile) |
  ForEach-Object Replace 'asdf', 'TESTREPLACE!' |
  Set-Content -NoNewLine -Encoding utf8 $ThisFile
```

With the `New-Item` workaround, if the output file mustn't have a BOM:

```bash
(Get-Content -Raw -Encoding utf8 $ThisFile) |
  ForEach-Object Replace 'asdf', 'TESTREPLACE!' |
  New-Item -Force $ThisFile |
  Out-Null   # suppress New-Item's output (a file-info object)
```

Comment: This was an excellent update but sadly it did not work when the AHK script tries to load back to the clipboard. It is still updating something in the binary file: more than just the string. I compared the original and new file via WinMerge:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhD4wIhahXFSo-VPEuEztafWNO6dqg?e=IbR2Hd

Comment: Also added this question, since it may easier to do all this entirely with PS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73806514/powershell-binary-clipboard-export-modify-and-import

Comment: @Ahmed: If you run the code with a replacement string of the same length, you'll see that no other bytes are changed. However, perhaps that is precisely the problem: the binary format may contain metadata as to the location and length of embedded strings (which is what fields such as `StartHTML` and `EndHTML` suggest), so if you change the length of those strings, you'd have to update that metadata too.

Comment: That makes sense! And you were right, the string replace worked fine when the text replace was the same length. Which actually solves my specific use case since I would only replace same-length strings.

I guess there is no universal solution to doing replacements when the replacement string length varies for binary clipboard data--even with PS. It seemed like the "metadata" was distributed throughout the file, too, when I did a comparison on the above file in WinMerge.